# NSwagStudio - generated C# client post not working

Tags: c#, json, nswagstudio

I generate a C# client from a .NET 4.8 Web API with NSwagStudio and everything works fine (all get requests) except for the posts. This is due to a wrong JSON serializer setting when converting an object to string.

If I construct the body like this

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(par), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

things work, but NSwagStudio uses something like this code:

```
var json_ = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myParams, _settings.Value);
var dictionary_ = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>(json_, _settings.Value);
var content_ = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary_);
```

which result in the body being null when received by the Web API. It seems the UTF8 setting is missing somewhere.

I guess I can fix this with some sort of `JsonSerializerSetting`, but I don't know where?

Comment: `FormUrlEncodedContent` <-- This is not JSON.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your Swagger file, I suspect your ASP.NET Web API controller action has incorrect `[Consumes]` attribute.

Comment: it is a .net 4.8 web api, so no [Consumes] attribute

Answer (score 0):

Check in the json have in consumes and produces only one type:

```
"consumes": [
             "application/json" 
             ],
"produces": [
             "application/json"
             ],
```

link #3414 NSwagstudio https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3414